# Why am I getting red lines when I'm using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I'm working on a small site for a startup
the site works well on desktops, but I'm trying to make it more responsive
using the Bootstrap grid system, however I'm getting red grid lines

What am I doing wrong?

Screenshot

[image]

HTML and CSS code below

```
<section class="tds-banner">
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="description">


<div class="container">

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <h1>Fishing Club Studios</h1>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col--xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <h5>We Make food and We drinks</h5>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-6">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary shadow mr-2">Food</a>

</div>
<div class="col-6">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary shadow mr-2">Drinks</a>
    </div>


</div>
</div>
</div>

    </section>



   <style>
  <!--CSS-->

  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 300px) {
        .tds-banner .overlay{
        position: absolute;
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
            background-image:url('/static                                                                                                      /talking_drumstudios_logo_360.png');
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: contain;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;

            }

              .description {
               font-size: 20px;
                border: none
                }



                   }
       </style>
```

Comment: You need to share some code

Comment: i think these red line are border of each div. Inspect element and add ```border:none```  in css.

Comment: check your css code for `border: 1px red solid;` set it to `border: none;`

Comment: @mitchel inaju Can you post your custom CSS?

Comment: @AlanGe ok sure i just did

Comment: @mitchelinaju, it doesn't look like all styles and html that you have. Could you please inspect your red-bordered elements and try to search these styles throw the project?

Comment: thanks alot, apparently i had a 
[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}               at the bottom of my css file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you find this kind of issues with borders using frameworks to override, inspect the element and try properties like:

```
border: none;
box-shadow: none;
outline: none;
```

About your text issues, I don't have access to your code but you probably have:

1. Reduce the padding on the container or margin on the divs, that's
   why you have all this white space on top and left.
2. Or I see that you're using position absolute in some cases, try using to the minimum otherwise you'll have more work trying to do the responsiveness.

Comment: ohh thanks alot, what do you mean try using to the minimum?

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it seems like you have assigned border to row or column class, try this CSS code:

```
.row,col-*{
border-width:0px;
}
```